# CloudFront - S3 origin failover and origin response timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to configure CloudFront distribution to use origin failover for S3 origins. Initially it looked like a great idea - when a region when a primary bucket resides is down, all requests are routed to the failover bucket automatically. In the CloudFront documentation however I found the following description related to Response Timeout:

> GET and HEAD requests – If Amazon S3 doesn't respond within 30 seconds or stops responding for 30 seconds, CloudFront drops the connection and makes two additional attempts to contact the origin. If the origin doesn't reply during the third attempt, CloudFront doesn't try again until it receives another request for content on the same CloudFront origin.
>
> For all requests, CloudFront attempts to establish a connection with S3. If the connection fails within 10 seconds, CloudFront drops the connection and makes two additional attempts to contact S3. If the origin doesn't reply during the third attempt, CloudFront doesn't try again until it receives another request for content on the same origin.
>
> The response timeout for S3 can't be changed.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorS3Origin.html#RequestS3RequestTimeout

Such high response timeouts together with the fact that CloudFront failover doesn't work like Route53 healt checks, i.e. it always tries to route traffic to the primary origin, even if previous requests failed, pose the question - is the CloudFront failover really practical solution for a rare situation when entire region may be down? It looks like in that case the performance of the website hosted via CloudFront would be really poor anyway. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bare in fact this response timeout is part of the health check not the user loading the request. If the origins unhealthy CloudFront will start directing all users traffic to the failover.

So there won't be performance issues for the users other than the 30 seconds where health checks are being performed, where CloudFront is actually performing the health checks to know if it should switch over

Comment: That was my initial thought as well, but I couldn't find any fragment in the documentation that can clearly support that assumption. The sentence 'CloudFront issues a connect timeout when it cannot connect to the origin after three consecutive attempts for a single request. CloudFront waits up to 10 seconds between connection attempts.' is really confusing and made me believe such process is repeated for each request.

Comment: Are you sure?  Do you have a link to the documentation regarding this behaviour?